# Simpler way to deal with Time and Date?

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to learn Haskell, so I am sorry if this has already been asked, but I could not find a question that properly answered my doubts.

So my question is given `UTCTime` what is the easiest and straightforward way of getting the following:

- Year
- Month
- Week
- Date (Eg: 24)
- Day (Eg: Monday)
- Hour
- Minutes
- Seconds

Also if there is convenient way of converting `UTCTime` to some local time using just `Asia/Tokyo` or similar strings.

I couldn't find a single library that gave all of these features and got confused and to be quite honest irritated that I need to convert between different types and use multiple libraries to achieve the above. Maybe I was not looking properly.

My effort so far:

```
import Data.Time

-- Difference between JST and UTC in seconds
-- JST is 9 hours ahead of UTC
utcJSTDiff :: Int
utcJSTDiff = 32400

getHour :: UTCTime -> Int
getHour time = todHour (timeToTimeOfDay (utctDayTime time))

getMinutes :: UTCTime -> Int
getMinutes time = todMin (timeToTimeOfDay (utctDayTime time))

isReminderHour :: Int -> Bool
isReminderHour hour
    | hour == morningReminderHour || hour == eveningReminderHour = True
    | otherwise = False

isReminderMins :: Int -> Bool
isReminderMins mins
    | mins <= reminderMinuteLimit = True
    | otherwise = False

timeforReminder :: UTCTime -> Bool
timeforReminder time
    | isReminderHour (getHour time) && isReminderMins (getMinutes time) = True
    | otherwise = False

utcToJST :: UTCTime -> UTCTime
utcToJST = addUTCTime (realToFrac utcJSTDiff)

main :: IO()
main = do
    currentTime <- getCurrentTime
    let jstTime = utcToJST currentTime
    if timeforReminder jstTime
        then action1
        else action2
```

Comment: Supplementary reading: https://two-wrongs.com/haskell-time-library-tutorial

Comment: @duplode I had already read that before asking this question, the main issue that tutorial does not cover is using timezones that are not derived from your machine, which IMHO is the most practical use, and I realize it's not the author's fault, Haskell time library simply does not provide a way of getting `TimeZone` other than that of the machine. Which if you ask me is really stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit:* Fixed to use `timezone-olson` / `timezone-series` for correct timezone processing.

You should be able to do almost everything with the `time` package, except that proper timezone processing will require `timezone-olson` and `timezone-series` packages on Linux systems; I'm not sure how to do it on Windows systems.  Maybe someone else has a better way.

Here's the code:

```
module Time where

import Data.Time                             -- package "time"
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate           -- package "time"
import Data.Time.LocalTime.TimeZone.Olson    -- package "timezone-olson"
import Data.Time.LocalTime.TimeZone.Series   -- package "timezone-series"

-- |POSIX-specific timezone lookup
lookupTimeZone :: String -> IO TimeZoneSeries
lookupTimeZone tz =
  getTimeZoneSeriesFromOlsonFile ("/usr/share/zoneinfo/" ++ tz)

data MyTime = MyTime
  { year :: Integer
  , month :: Int
  , week :: Int
  , dayOfMonth :: Int
  , dayOfWeek :: Int
  , hour :: Int
  , minutes :: Int
  , seconds :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

getMyTime :: TimeZoneSeries -> UTCTime -> MyTime
getMyTime tz t =
  let LocalTime day (TimeOfDay hh mm ss) = utcToLocalTime' tz t
      (yr, mn, dom) = toGregorian day
      (_,  wk, dow) = toWeekDate day
  in MyTime yr mn wk dom dow hh mm (round ss)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  -- Note: if you want time in local timezone, use:
  -- tz <- getTimeZoneSeriesFromOlsonFile "/etc/localtime"
  tz <- lookupTimeZone "Asia/Tokyo"
  print $ getMyTime tz currentTime
```

A few cautionary notes:

- `lookupTimeZone` will throw an exception if it can't find the timezone file at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/your/timezone`
- If by "week", you meant "week of the year", you may want to consult the documentation for `toWeekDate` to see exactly how that's defined.
- If you want months or days in string format, you can use the functions in `Data.Time.Format` (still in the `time` package) to format them in the current (or some other) locale.

Comment: thanks! this does the work, but I wonder if there was better documentation, maybe I wouldn't have needed to ask this question. Documentation on hackage is next to useless with zero examples, is there something like this [golang time package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) for haskell (in terms of documentation and examples)?  
Also can you also give example for the Date.Time.Format?

Comment: The link @duplode gives above looks like it provides good documentation.  To translate numeric month and day of week to text, you can use the `defaultTimeLocale` value directly:   for example, `fst (months defaultTimeLocale !! 5)` and `fst (wDays defaultTimeLocale !! 1)` give full names or use `snd` instead of `fst` to get abbreviated names.  More complex time formatting is possible, too, with the `formatTime` function:  (e.g., `formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%A, %B %-e at %-H hours, %-M minutes" <$> getCurrentTime`).