# How to find out if it's summer or winter time?

Tags: haskell

I want to find out if on a certain [`Day`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/libraries/time-1.8.0.2/Data-Time-Calendar.html#t:Day) (package `time`) it's summer time or winter time.

I am especially interested in central Europe, where in summer the timezone is CEST = GMT+2 and in winter CEST = GMT+1.

I need it because I need to convert [`JulianDate`](https://aligusnet.github.io/astro-docs/doc/astro-0.4.2.1/Data-Astro-Time-JulianDate.html) (package `astro`) to local time and back.

Comment: Assuming you are doing this under Linux, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43837250/7203016) helpful.  In a nutshell, you can use the timezone database in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` to perform accurate local time conversions..

Comment: You should watch this video on time zones if you have not already: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Thanks, unfortunately I happen to only have Windows in reach at the moment, but I didn't know about it - thanks for providing the link for linux users. Will maybe try when I'm at home at linux again ;)

Comment: @JohnF.Miller Indeed, I'm still hoping that the DST will be removed in Europe, there's some rumours so who knows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the exact dates on which the timezone changes differ per place, I think you have to write your own function which check this.

I happen to know in Europe summer time starts on the last Sunday of March, and ends at the last Sunday of October. I used this in the function below, it's easy to change for other locations.

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate
import Data.Tuple.Select

-- | Uses only days, it does not take the exact hour into account at which summer time starts and ends.
isSummerTime :: Day -- ^ Date to check if summer time is active
            -> Bool -- ^ Whether summer time is active
isSummerTime date = date > lastSundayMarch && date < lastSundayOctober
    where
        year = sel1 $ toGregorian date
        -- Find last Sunday in March
        aprilOne = fromGregorian year 4 1
        -- 1 is Monday, ..., 7 is Sunday
        aprilOneWeekDay = sel3 $ toWeekDate aprilOne
        -- Use the day number to find Sunday of the previous week: the last Sunday in March
        lastSundayMarch = addDays (-(toInteger aprilOneWeekDay)) aprilOne
        -- Same for end of summer time in October
        novemberOne = fromGregorian year 11 1
        novemberOneWeekDay = sel3 $ toWeekDate novemberOne
        lastSundayOctober = addDays (-(toInteger novemberOneWeekDay)) novemberOne

isSummerTime $ fromGregorian 2018 3 25 -- False
isSummerTime $ fromGregorian 2018 3 26 -- True
isSummerTime $ fromGregorian 2018 10 27 -- True
isSummerTime $ fromGregorian 2018 10 28 -- False
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a program that needs to run on a cloud server on UTC, but care about times in the USA Pacific time zone. I adapted @PHPirate's answer to follow the rules in the USA:

- **Start** on the 2nd Sunday of March at 2 AM PST (1000 UTC)
- **End** on the 1st Sunday of November at 2 AM PDT (0900 UTC)

I'm leaving this here for any future Haskellers looking for code to be smart about Daylight Savings

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate

-- | Get the current time in the Pacific time zone, accounting for Daylight
-- Savings Time
getCurrentTimePacific :: IO ZonedTime 
getCurrentTimePacific = do
    rightNow <- getCurrentTime
    let timeZoneStr = if isDaylightSavings rightNow then "PDT" else "PST"
        pacificTimeZone = read timeZoneStr
    return $ utcToZonedTime pacificTimeZone rightNow

-- | Determine whether the USA Pacific time zone is in Daylight Savings time
isDaylightSavings :: UTCTime -> Bool
isDaylightSavings utcIn = utcIn >= dstStart && utcIn < dstEnd
  where
    (year, _, _) = toGregorian (utctDay utcIn)
    (dstStart, dstEnd) = pacificDSTBoundsInUTC year

-- | Start and end boundaries of daylight savings time for Pacific zone, in UTC
pacificDSTBoundsInUTC :: 
       Integer            -- ^ Year for Daylight Savings calculation
    -> (UTCTime, UTCTime) -- ^ (start, end) of Pacific daylight savings in UTC
pacificDSTBoundsInUTC year = let
    secondSundayMarch = getNthSundayOfMonth year 3 2
    firstSundayNovember = getNthSundayOfMonth year 11 1
    dstChangeTime = TimeOfDay 2 0 0 -- 2 AM
    toDaylightSavingsPoint = ZonedTime 
        (LocalTime secondSundayMarch dstChangeTime) (read "PST")
    fromDaylightSavingsPoint = ZonedTime 
        (LocalTime firstSundayNovember dstChangeTime) (read "PDT")
    in
    (  zonedTimeToUTC toDaylightSavingsPoint
     , zonedTimeToUTC fromDaylightSavingsPoint) 

-- | Get the nth Sunday of a month
getNthSundayOfMonth :: 
       Integer -- ^ Year
    -> Int     -- ^ Month
    -> Int     -- ^ nth Sunday to get
    -> Day     -- Day object for nth Sunday
getNthSundayOfMonth year month sundayN = let
    sundayDay = 7
    firstOfMonth = fromGregorian year month 1
    (_, _, firstOfMonthWeekDay) = toWeekDate firstOfMonth
    daysDiffToFirstSunday = sundayDay - firstOfMonthWeekDay
    daysToAddToFirst = daysDiffToFirstSunday + (sundayN - 1) * sundayDay
    in
    addDays (toInteger daysToAddToFirst) firstOfMonth
```

The core function, which computes the DST bounds, gives these results

```
pacificDSTBoundsInUTC 2021 == (2021-03-14 10:00:00 UTC,2021-11-07 09:00:00 UTC)
pacificDSTBoundsInUTC 2020 == (2020-03-08 10:00:00 UTC,2020-11-01 09:00:00 UTC)
pacificDSTBoundsInUTC 2019 == (2019-03-10 10:00:00 UTC,2019-11-03 09:00:00 UTC)
```